# Created method, having trouble returning a variable in it

Tags: java, xml, variables, methods, return

In this method, an XML file is read and certain information about it is put into a list. I have everything else working for all of the code/other methods, I am just having trouble returning the "list" variable.

```
package ca3;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

public class xmlReader{

    public String fileName;
    public xmlReader (String fileLoca){
        fileName=fileLoca;
    }

    public List list;

    public List returnLists(String fileN)
    {
        mp3Lister woww = null;
        String fName;
        String lName;
        mp3Lister qwewq;
    try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File(fileN));

            // normalize text representation
            doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
            System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " +
                 doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

            NodeList listOfPersons = doc.getElementsByTagName("person");
            int totalPersons = listOfPersons.getLength();
            System.out.println("Total no of people : " + totalPersons);
            List list = new LinkedList();    // Doubly-linked list

            for(int s=0; s<listOfPersons.getLength() ; s++){
                Node firstPersonNode = listOfPersons.item(s);
                if(firstPersonNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                    Element firstPersonElement = (Element)firstPersonNode;

                    //-------
                    NodeList firstNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("first");
                    Element firstNameElement = (Element)firstNameList.item(0);

                    NodeList textFNList = firstNameElement.getChildNodes();
//                    System.out.println("First Name : " +
//                           ((Node)textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

//                            
                    //-------
                    NodeList lastNameList = firstPersonElement.getElementsByTagName("last");
                    Element lastNameElement = (Element)lastNameList.item(0);

                    NodeList textLNList = lastNameElement.getChildNodes();
//                    System.out.println("Last Name : " +
//                           ((Node)textLNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());

                    lName = textLNList.item(0).getNodeValue().trim().toString();
                    fName = textFNList.item(0).getNodeValue().trim().toString();
                    mp3Lister[] wowow = null;

                    woww = new mp3Lister(fName,lName);

                    list.add(woww);
                    //----

                    //------

                }//end of if clause

//                qwewq = (mp3Lister) list.get(0);
//                System.out.println(qwewq.getTitle() + " wakakakakaka");

            }//end of for loop with s var
            //end of for loop with s var

        }catch (SAXParseException err) {
        System.out.println ("** Parsing error" + ", line "
             + err.getLineNumber () + ", uri " + err.getSystemId ());
        System.out.println(" " + err.getMessage ());

        }catch (SAXException e) {
        Exception x = e.getException ();
        ((x == null) ? e : x).printStackTrace ();

        }catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace ();
        }

return list;
        //System.exit (0);

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the 'trouble' you're facing?

Comment: what method you call and what you expect to have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you meant to return the `list` local variable that you declare in the `returnLists` function. What you'll be getting back is actually the class variable, also called `list`. This is because the local `list` variable has gone out of context by the time the code reaches your return statement (the local `list` variable is within the context of the `try` block you have declared). If you want to return the value from the local `list` variable change the first couple of lines of `returnLists` to this:

```
public List returnLists(String fileN)
    {
        mp3Lister woww = null;
        String fName;
        String lName;
        mp3Lister qwewq;
        List list = new LinkedList();
    try {
```

and then remove the declaration of the `list` variable inside the try block.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing you have a local variable called list and a class variable called list. In the lines 'list = ArrayList();' and the line 'List list = new LinkedList();' the runtime will have trouble evaluating which List instance it is evaluating. When you return you may get completely meaningless nonsense results.

Note I only looked at this code for a total of a minute, so this is very likely wrong, but this is what jumped out at me immediately.

Comment: Ughh, sorry my mistake. I forgot to delete that part from the code. That was from a bit of testing.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem : You have declared `list` as a global variable. In the `returnList` method you are again declaring a variable `list` in try block.  You should either remove the local variable or remove the global variable.

Comment: When I get rid of the global variable, it gives me a "cannot find symbol" error. 

Also, when I try and run the method either way. It gives me a "null pointer exception error.

Comment: always give the stack trace or the line number where an error is occurring if you want help fixing it

Comment: @willkara Remove the global declaration and move your local variable declaration outside of try block.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are returning list from outside the try block, but you are declaring it within the try block. 
Either declare

```
List list = null;
```

outside the try block and instantiate

```
list = new LinkedList();
```

inside the try block.

or

```
return list;
```

from inside the try block.

I hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

the list variable which you are **returning** is the **member variable list**. because the list variable in the method returnlist is declared in the try block **which ends its scope** once the control is out of the try block. so declare the list variable **before try block**.